# Learning with rounding (LWR)

Tags: lattice-crypto

This may be a naive question:

LWR assumption states that for ${A} \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}_q, s \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^n_q$, given $(A, \lfloor A\cdot s \rfloor_p$), it is indistinguishable from $(A, u)$ with $u \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^m_p$.
There seems to be no specific condition on $m$ and $n$ except $m,n \geq 1$.

My question is does this hold true for $m = n = 1$? It does not seem right to me, kindly explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There seems to be no specific condition on $m$ and $n$ except $m,n \geq 1$.

The LWR assumption isn't that the problem is hard for any arbitrary $m, n$, it's there it's true for the specific $m, n$ pairs we use in practice.  Obviously, for $m=n=1$, it's an easy problem; that's not particularly relevant, as we don't use $m=n=1$.

This is similar to the RSA assumption; that assumption isn't that it's a hard problem for arbitrary sized keys (it's not for, say, 10 bit keys); it's that it's a hard problem for the key sizes we use in practice (for example, 3072 bit correctly generated keys).